# Why does my function always returns false, even if it finds return true before?

Tags: java, return

```
public boolean contains(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head.getNext();

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(current.getData());
        if(temp.getData() == current.getData())
        {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code is above and it returns false no matter what. If it finds a true condition, it prints "true" and it still returns false. What am I doing wrong here? I have exact same function, except it's returning an integer instead of boolean and it works perfectly fine with the same method/code.4

My function which does the same and works fine:

```
public int indexOf(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head.getNext();

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        if(temp.getData() == current.getData())
        {
            return i;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to add more context. We can't just guess. Provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis All I'm doing is `if(LL.contains("something") == true) //print`

Comment: How do you compare Strings in Java? I doubt that prints `"true"`.

Comment: LL is an object (singly linked list) which contains 3 nodes, the code is too big to add (200+ lines)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have the exact same code, except using Integer instead of Boolean in another method and it returns the correct value. I'll attach that method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an issue with this expression:

```
if(temp.getData() == current.getData())
```

It's bad enough that your data is represented by `Object` - it *really* should be a parameterized type* instead.  But, since you're using `==`, you're checking to see if the object is the same *instance*, not if they're equivalent.

Change your comparison to use `.equals` instead.

```
if(temp.getData().equals(current.getData())
```

*:  In case you were wondering, you'd change your `Node` to a `Node<T>` instead, change your linked list instance to be typed to `LinkedList<Node<T>>`, and change the method argument of `contains` to be `public boolean contains(T data)`.